# Google webmastertools rejects submitted RSS feed

Tags: rss, google-search-console

In Google Webmastertools I try to test and submit a RSS feed, this can be done in the section 'Crawl' > 'Sitemaps'. Now, when Google Webmastertools is testing my submitted URL of the RSS feed, it repeatedly gives an error:
"Network unreachable: Network unreachable
We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit."

The RSS feed I submitted http://www.harrieboerhof.nl/nl/over-harrieboerhof-hovenier-tuincentrum-modeltuinen-drenthe/blog/?format=feed&type=rss
seems allright to me, what could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without doing anything else, Google Webmastertools suddenly accepts my RSS feed...
So, just try to do the same thing after half an hour!